# Reading static file in java using ant build

Tags: java, ant

I am new to ANT and having some trouble handling static files which I need to read via my Java code. I have the following structure:

```
build
  main
    example
      resository
        SomeClass.class   
data
  data.json
src
  example
    repository
      SomeClass.java
test
```

In SomeClass.java I need to read the `data.json` file but I am getting error in resolving path. I think its related to `ant` somehow.

```
public class SomeClass {
  class SomeClass extends ArrayList<Quote> {}

  public Quote[] all() {
    String path = "../../../data/data.json";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
      return gson.fromJson(br, Quote[].class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    return new Quote[]{};
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

I think since ant it putting the files in `build` folder hence I may need to put my files somewhere there too, I have tried that too but I think I need some more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative path is calculated relative from the execution directory.
If you execute `ant` in the project root,
then the relative path from there is `data/data.json`, not `../../../data/data.json`.

When getting "File not found" errors,
it's good to verify the execution directory, either in a debugger,
or by inserting a print statement, for example:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

From the output, you will know faire and square in which directory the process is running in,
and you will be able to calculate the correct relative path.

Comment: I don't know how many hours of life I have wasted finding this, why java has to do this to me.

Comment: Just one more thing, in production I would like to ship everything in a single file, can I somehow put my data file in the build folder and reference it from there?

Comment: That will depend on the execution directory of the process that will run your program.